# Filter by the field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I added field move_name in tree view and i want to make filter based if there is move_name or not. There is invoices with move names and some of them without so when i enable filter the should be only invoices with move_names. i tried adding it to search view but i think i have problem with domain. when i click on filter every invoice disappears.

```
 <record id="invoice_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.invoice.tree</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='number']" position="after">
                    <field name="move_name"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_account_invoice_filter_contract" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.invoice.select.contract</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_invoice_filter"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <filter name="draft" position="before">
                    <filter string="Move" name="move" domain="[('move_name','=','True')]"/>
                </filter>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Please share the fields structure for move_name and invoices.

Comment: move_name = fields.Char(string='Journal Entry', readonly=False,
        default=False, copy=False) it's original field from account.invoice model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that domain should be domain="[('move_name','!=','False')]"